# Modifying function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add custom event listener

```
$(document).on('customEvent', function(e, message) {
   message = 'Hello world';
});
```

Somewhere else I trigger it:

```
var message = 'no message';
$(document).trigger('customEvent', message);
// I want here message to be `Hello world`
```

Is there any way to get updated message, without assigning it to some global variable?

I want to create something like [WordPress filter API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters), just with jQuery.

Comment: use automatically invoked function to wrap everything.

Comment: Event can be binded anywhere, even in a separate file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of passing a message string, pass a message object with the message string as the member.

```
$(document).on('customEvent', function(e, messageObj) {
   messageObj.messageStr= 'Hello world';
});

var messageObj = {'messageStr':'initial Message'};
$(document).trigger('customEvent', messageObj );
```

In the trigger, you update the messageStr member of your object. You would have the data.

But you need to make sure that your code is not asynchronous. Only way to insure is to employ call backs from the trigger.

Comment: Yay for objects being passed by reference :-)

Answer (score 2):

If all your JS code can be grouped together then you can use this approach:

```
(function() {
    $(document).on('customEvent', function(e, message) {
       sharedMessage = message;
    });
    ...
    var message = 'no message';
    $(document).trigger('customEvent', 'hello, world!');
}());
```

Since javascript variables are function scoped, any `var` inside that function will not be global.  If not, you can create your own, unlikely to collide, namespace:

```
var reallyunlikelytocollidenamespace = {};
reallyunlikelytocollidenamespace.message = 'no message';
...
```

Comment: This won't work.  Inside the bound event, `message` will be the local variable, not the "global" variable.  For it to work, you need to declare `var message` before the event is bound, and also not have `message` be a parameter.  Also, you need to declare your "namespace" as an object before you can assign to it.  `var a; a.test = 123;` doesn't work.  It needs to be `var a = {};`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat you are indeed right, it was cut/paste from the original post...  updated to show what i think he was meaning to say.  and yes, need the object assignment as well.  also updated.